# Error when using Emgu CV C#

Tags: c#, emgucv

I'm new to Emgu and was learning with a C# code tutorial off the Internet. In the code, I am getting that certain elements such as img[channel] (line 15) and NewImage("Background segmented", image) (line 21) are not referenced. But I have added the appropriate DLLs and references. Can you please let me know if I am missing anything here?

```
using Emgu;
using Emgu.CV;
using Emgu.Util;
using Emgu.CV.CvEnum;
using Emgu.CV.Util;
using Emgu.CV.Structure;

private void CielabChannelMaskBGSubtraction(string filename, bool displayResult)
        {
        double threshold = double.Parse(max2textBox.Text);

        Image<Bgr, byte> rgb = new Image<Bgr, byte>(filename);
        Image<Lab, Byte> img = rgb.Convert<Lab, Byte>();

        //get the a* channel 
        Image<Gray, Byte> gray = img[channel];

        //threshold and invert
        gray = gray.ThresholdBinary(new Gray(threshold), new Gray(255)).Not();

        // display the result
        if (displayResult) this.NewImage("Background segmented", image);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are trying to pass in variables `channel` and `image` but those variables do not exist.

It looks, for example like channel is supposed to be accessing an elemnt in the array, so you would have to define it. Something like

```
int channel = 0; // this would get you the first channel in the img array
```

And image is never declared either. You can't use variables that haven't been defined

Comment: Thanks I'l try it out.. I have one more query.. In the last line of the code, I have a reference to NewImage(). But it shows an error stating that the method is not found and that I might be missing a reference or an assembly. Any advice on this??